# pandas: merge strings when other columns satisfy a condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a table:

```
genome  start   end   strand    etc
GUT_GENOME270877.fasta  98  396 +   
GUT_GENOME270877.fasta  384 574 -
GUT_GENOME270877.fasta  593 984 +
GUT_GENOME270877.fasta  991 999 -
```

I'd like to make a new table with column `coordinates`, which joins `start` and `end` columns and looking like this:

```
genome  start   end   strand    etc   coordinates
GUT_GENOME270877.fasta  98  396 +   98..396
GUT_GENOME270877.fasta  384 574 -   complement(384..574)
GUT_GENOME270877.fasta  593 984 +   593..984
GUT_GENOME270877.fasta  991 999 -   complement(991..999)
```

so that if there's a `-` in the `etc` column, I'd like to do not just

`df['coordinates'] = df['start'].astype(str) + '..' + df['end'].astype(str)`

but to add *brackets* and *complement*, like this:

`df['coordinates'] = 'complement(' + df['start'].astype(str) + '..' + df['end'].astype(str) + ')'`

The only things i'm missing is how to introduce the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['strand'].eq('-')

df['coordinates'] = (np.where(m, 'complement(', '')
                    +df['start'].astype(str)+'..'+df['end'].astype(str)
                    +np.where(m, ')', '')
                    )
```

Or [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['strand'].eq('-')

df['coordinates'] = df['start'].astype(str)+'..'+df['end'].astype(str)

df.loc[m, 'coordinates'] = 'complement('+df.loc[m, 'coordinates']+')'
```

Output:

```
                   genome  start  end strand           coordinates
0  GUT_GENOME270877.fasta     98  396      +               98..396
1  GUT_GENOME270877.fasta    384  574      -  complement(384..574)
2  GUT_GENOME270877.fasta    593  984      +              593..984
3  GUT_GENOME270877.fasta    991  999      -  complement(991..999)
```